# Reference needed for Novikov paper

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, manifolds, spheres, surgery-theory

I'm having trouble finding this construction.

Novikov (1964) constructed homotopy equivalences $f:N\rightarrow S^p\times S^q$ for $p,q > 1$ which are not homotopic to homeomorphisms.

References? --thanks

Comment: take a look at ch 3 of Topological Library: Part 2: Characteristic Classes and Smooth Structures on Manifolds (Series on Knots and Everything).